# Anyone know any HTTP chat clints

Tags: http, encryption, wireshark, pcap

I am setting up a .pcap file to give as a training challenge. So I want the basic idea to be to find messages sent from host A to host B, and I need a HTTP/or some sort of insecure local chat client, so the messages won't be encrypted in the .pcap

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the getting started guide (chat app track) from socket.io. It has you creating your own local (non-encrypted) chat application.

http://socket.io/get-started/chat/